# Draggable only in a div

Tags: html, draggable

I've got this code:

```
<div class="project">
  <div class="main">
    Here are many images
  </div>
</div>
```

The div.project has width as the width of body, the width of div.main is sum of width of all images inside it, and it's much wider than the body. Images use float:left.

How do I make it so (using draggable or something else) that I can scroll right/left to see all the images?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `overflow: scroll` on your class main

You would have to have an outer div called window or something that wraps around your content. That window will have to have `overflow: hidden` on it. Then you could use jquery to increase/decrease the margin on the content div on a button press to depict scrolling.

Comment: Ok, but how to do this without scrollbar? Or how to hide it on move with mouse wheel?